# Passing name of server from a list to nslookup with Awk

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, nslookup

Backstory: I am making a script to check a blacklist of domains and see which domains are still valid (resolve to an IP) so I can cut out the old non-resolving domains from the list. The list has millions of lines, so I am using awk (instead of a "do while read") to increase speed.

I am trying to write an awk statement that will nslookup a list of domains and print only the list of resolve-able domains to another list.

I am almost finished except I am stuck on one part- how can I specify the server that nslookup uses?

I have -port=54 working, but I am also trying to configure which DNS server nslookup uses.

```
awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list | nslookup -port=54| awk '/[Nn]ame/ {print $NF}'  >> /etc/pihole/gravityProcessed.list
```

If I try to specify -server= this is not a valid parameter
If I try to change the nslookup to use 1.1.1.1, instead of using 1.1.1.1 as the server, it tries to nslookup 1.1.1.1 instead.

```
awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list | nslookup 1.1.1.1 | awk '/[Nn]ame/ {print $NF}'  >> /etc/pihole/gravityProcessed.list
```

The issue is that nslookup doesnt have a -server parameter afaik (yes it has a -port parameter)
So I need awk to do:

```
nslookup [INSERT HOST] server -port=
```

Here is a sample of /etc/pihole/gravity.list

```
google.com
yahoo.com
skype.com
microsoft.com
```

The other option I wish to try to incorporate is a regex of a proper domain syntax as the script currently dies if it hits a domain that isnt formatted properly. Like putting this through a grep

    `(?=^.{4,253}$)(^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)`

Comment: Why are you using `awk` at the beginning of the pipeline when you could be using `cat`?

Comment: The file I am trying to parse is really big- 4 million lines. According to this post, awk will parse it faster than cat. https://askubuntu.com/questions/564944/cat-vs-grep-vs-awk-command-get-the-file-content-which-one-is-more-efficient-and I had tried reading line by line with "While read" and it was super slow

Comment: Not sure what you want. Something like `nslookup $(awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list) -port=54` (only when `awk`returns one result) or `awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list | xargs -L1 -I{} nslookup {} -port=54` ?

Comment: @Spencer I doubt if they should be using `cat` (google UUOC) - if nslookup needs whole lines from gravity.list then either nslookup can read a file on it's own or input can be reidrected with `<`. p1* - see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for why a while read is super slow.

Comment: Are you trying to call nslookup 4 million times, and parse the results also 4 million times? Can you reduce the number of lookups with `cut -f1 /etc/pihole/gravity.list | sort -u` (perhaps add `-d " "` when fields are seperated by spaces) ?

Comment: @p1r473 if you post a small sample of gravity.list and what you need to extract from it to pass to nslookup then we can help with that part and similarly if you post the output from nslookup and what you want to print given that then we can help with that part too.

Comment: `nslookup` doesn't get the name to look for from standard input, why are you piping to `nslookup`?

Comment: @Walter Yes, I am trying to call nslookup 4 million times. The PiHole application takes many hostsfiles and blocklists available online and merges them into 1 mega one. However, many of these lists are unmaintained. I am trying to get rid of the hostnames that no longer resolve to an IP.

Comment: @Barmar I just simply need to get a sublist of hostnames that resolve to an IP.

Comment: The other option I wish to try to incorporate is a regex of a proper domain syntax as the script currently dies if it hits a domain that isnt formatted properly. Like putting this through a grep (?=^.{4,253}$)(^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$)

Comment: @Walter, I am not familiar with cut. Where in the awk would I put cut -f1 /etc/pihole/gravity.list | sort -u

Comment: @EdMorton gravity.list is simply a list of domains. 1 domain per line. So google.com, google.ca, yahoo.com, etc.

Comment: Great, include a sample of it in your question.

Comment: @p1r473 use `cut` from the prompt. First try `echo "this is an example"| cut -d" " -f2`, play with it and then try `head -100 /etc/pihole/gravity.list | cut -f1 -d" " | sort -u`. With `head` you can test with a subset.

Comment: Isn't what you want `xargs`? Read the output of a command and put it as a argument to another command? `</etc/pihole/gravity.list xargs -I{} nslookup {}` ?

Comment: @Walter I tried `cut -f1 /etc/pihole/gravity.list | sort -u` and it seemed to just spit out the whole list. Are you trying to remove duplicates, as the list is already deduplicated.

Comment: Can't nslookup simply read input for itself though? I posted an "answer" to try to move the question along a bit faster.

Comment: @Kamil I cant find a way to make xargs append a server parameter, like "1.1.1.1" and pass it to the nslookup

Comment: Other utilities could be easier to parse ex, `host` `</etc/pihole/gravity.list xargs -I{} nslookup {} 1.1.1.1`. Use `-t` option to xargs to see what hes doing. Or add `echo` in front of nslookup to make it just print the line. This is really XY question, are you really interested in how to pass a paremeter? Because your goal looks to be "how to change list of domains to ip addresses using specific dns server". `</etc/pihole/gravity.list xargs -I{} nslookup {} 1.1.1.1 -port=54`. The `{}` is just substituted for each line.

Comment: Unfortunately host cannot specify the -port parameter and I am trying to resolve with a local resolver listening on -port=54. This is why I switched to nslookup from host. The parsing is working, its trying to send an extra parameter e.g. 1.1.1.1, a resolver, to the awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use an alternative nameserver, look at the following instruction for `nslookup`:

> ARGUMENTS
>   Interactive mode is entered in the following cases:
>   1. when no arguments are given (the default name server will be used)
>   2. when the first argument is a hyphen (-) and the second argument is the host name or Internet address of a name server.

So try

```
nslookup - 1.1.1.1 < /etc/pihole/gravity.list 2>/dev/null | 
   awk '/[Nn]ame/ {print $NF}' >> /etc/pihole/gravityProcessed.list
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. This worked perfectly. I just forgot the hyphen. Final line is: 
    awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list |nslookup - 127.0.0.1 -port=54 < /etc/pihole/gravity.list 2>/dev/null | awk '/[Nn]ame/ {print $NF}' >> /etc/pihole/gravityProcessed.list

Walter, I am new here, but for my question # 2, which is passing this through a regex to verify the domain is valid, should that be a new question?

Comment: It should be a new question. First try the simplified `sed -rn '/^(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/p' /etc/pihole/gravity.list | nslookup - 1.1.1.1 2>/dev/null | 
   awk '/[Nn]ame/ {print $NF}' >> /etc/pihole/gravityProcessed.list`, perhaps you can work this out.

Comment: @p1r473 what do you think `awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list |nslookup - 127.0.0.1 -port=54 < /etc/pihole/gravity.list` means wrt where `nslookup` is getting it's input from? It's important that you understand this.

Comment: Forget good/bad domains - the point is **you** in the command you posted that I copied into my comment, are piping the output of an awk command to the stdin of nslookup (`awk '{print $1}' /etc/pihole/gravity.list |nslookup ...`) and at the same time redirecting the contents of gravity.list to the stdin of nslookup (`nslookup ... < /etc/pihole/gravity.list`). So where do you intend nslookup to actually read it's stdin from? I just want to make sure you understand what those commands you were using are doing so you can see that it doesn't make sense to both pipe into and redirect into a command.

Comment: wrt bad domains - if that regexp you posted does what you want then you can remove the input redirection and do `grep -P 'that regexp' | nslookup - 1.1.1.1 2>/dev/null | awk '...'` instead.